# Orchard CMS: Help Building 1 to n Relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I was reading http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations#Building_an_iN-Ni_Relationship_34 but it doesn't seem to say what files should be created and where.  For instance, the first part says, "Here is the code for the Address part" but it doesn't say what name to save the file as and where to put it.  Can someone tell me what to do?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could download the source-zip and have a look.
2. You could look at the code of the `class` eg:

   ```
   namespace RelationSample.Models {
       public class AddressPart : ContentPart<AddressPartRecord>
   ```

   Which tells you to create a folder named *Models* and put a file *AddressPart.cs* into it.

Comment: Is the example supposed to be in a module?  Should I create a new module and start adding these classes to it?

Comment: I use the command line to set up a new project: eg. codegen module RelationSample
 - check http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Building-a-hello-world-module

Comment: @user1477388 Everything you do in Orchard has to be in some module. So  you're exactly right - create a new module and add things to it.

Comment: Guys, I am trying to debug my module.  I followed the exact steps of http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations#Building_an_iN-Ni_Relationship_34 except instead of creating a new module, I used my HelloWorld one.  I removed the controller and the routes, making it identical to the RelationSample.  I changed the "using" calls and related items from "RelationSample" to "HelloWorld."  How do I debug a module like this?  The problem is, it isn't adding the ContentPart "Address."